# can get random number guesser to remember if it was to high or to low

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am working on a random number guesser where the user inputs a number between 1 and 100 and the computer try's to guess the number. the user can say if the guess was to high or to low and the program will guess accordingly.

I am having issues with getting the program to correctly filter the numbers if it was to high or to low, it keep of just guessing random numbers

```
def main():
    number = int(input("Enter a number between 1-100: "))
    if number < 1:
        print("Please pick a number between 1-100")
        main()
    elif number > 100:
        print("Please pick a number between 1-100")
        main()
    guesser(number)
    
    
def guesser(number):
    low = 1
    high = 100
    guess = 0
    while guess != number:
        guess = random.randint(low, high)
        info = input("Is {:2d} low or high? ".format(guess))
        info = info.lower
        if info == "high":
            high =+ guess
        elif info == "low":
            low =+ guess 
        elif info == "yes":
            print("Yay")
```

this is what I have so far.

Comment: This is unclear. From what I understand, you have a random number which the user should guess ? If the guess is too low it tells the user it's too low and if it's too high same deal. And the user can enter new inputs until he lands on the right value. Is that right ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the guesser program.

I have made some changes:

- f-string added for readability, eg: print(f"hi {value}")  input(f"hi {value}: ")
- `yes` added for asking user if guess is correct or not (message in input())
- `lower` function call added with the `input-getting` line, and function call required `()` also, not only `lower` word
- The `=+` doesn't work as expected so there's a change in logic

  - if `info == high` then `high = guess - 1`

    - Since the user says that `guess is higher than answer`, we should `replace the high number` as `guess - 1`

      - That is, if answer is `50` and computer guess is `63` then high will be set to `(guess - 1) = (63 - 1) = 62` because `63 is wrong, next higher limit should be (63 - 1) = 62`
  - if `info == low` then `low = guess + 1`

    - Since the user says that `guess is lower than answer`, we should `replace the low number` as `guess + 1`

      - That is, if answer is `50` and computer guess is `23` then low will be set to `(guess + 1) = (23 + 1) = 24` because `23 is wrong, next lower limit should be (23 + 1) = 24`
  - So using this logic, the computer can bring down the guess limits smaller with each iteration, like:

```
Enter a number between 1-100: 50
Is 21 low or high or yes? l
guess = random.randint(22, 100)

Is 65 low or high or yes? h
guess = random.randint(22, 64)

Is 52 low or high or yes? h
guess = random.randint(22, 51)

Is 48 low or high or yes? l
guess = random.randint(49, 52)

Is 50 low or high or yes? yes
Yay
```

Now try this code:

```
def guesser(number):
    low = 1
    high = 100
    guess = 0
    while guess != number:
        guess = random.randint(low, high)
        info = input(f"Is {guess} low or high or yes? ").lower()
        if info == "h":
            high = guess - 1
        elif info == "l":
            low = guess + 1
        elif info == "yes":
            print("Yay")
```

You could improve the program with some other changes like

- Asking the user, if he/she like to `play again`.

  - Put the `main` function in a `while loop` and at last add `if input("Again? y/n: ") != 'y': break`
- You could modify the program by `giving the lower & upper limits` for the computer `to choose random numbers`. But `keep the secret number in your mind`, and `when the computer guesses the secret number, reply as correct`